# Google Analytics 4 Ecommerce: Problems with item_list_id in view_item_list

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

i'm using google analytics with google tag manager.

I created a "view_item_list" event. If i send my dummy data via datalayer to GA4 then the debug view shows to much items because the "item_list_name" and the "item_list_id" showen like a item (both items have the same value).

[GA4 Debug view result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBwrH.png)

[Datalayer from GTM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSfdz.png)

[GTM Event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oszzX.png)

```
window.dataLayer=window.dataLayer||[],window.dataLayer.push({event:"view_item_list",ecommerce:{items:[{item_id:"TEST-1",item_name:"TEST-1",price:20,currency:"EUR"},{item_id:"TEST-2",item_name:"TEST-2",price:30,currency:"EUR"},{item_id:"TEST-3",item_name:"TEST-3",price:40,currency:"EUR"}],item_list_name:"Testlist 1",item_list_id:"testlist1"},user_login:"admin",user_id:1,user_role:"administrator"});
```

Have anyone an idea whats wrong?

Comment: Looks good to me. How did you set up your variables ?

Also might be a GA4 bug, I somehow could not see my view_list_item event in debug view lately.

Comment: omg I have the same thing happening for me. Not sure if it's a bug, or it should be like that.

Comment: @SteffenG Did you get this resolved

Comment: I do have the same thing going on