# view_list_item list id and name not working properly

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I'm using Google Tag Manager to deploy Google Analytics 4. I want to use view_list_items. If I follow this [Google example](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ecommerce-ga4#measure_productitem_list_viewsimpressions) and push the following JSON with a variable ecommerce.items mapped to the items parameter of a view_item_list event:

```
dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'view_item_list',
  'ecommerce': {
    'items': [
     {
       'item_name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt',       // Name or ID is required.
       'item_id': '12345',
       'price': '15.25',
       'item_brand': 'Google',
       'item_category': 'Apparel',
       'item_category2': 'Mens',
       'item_category3': 'Shirts',
       'item_category4': 'Tshirts',
       'item_variant': 'Gray',
       'item_list_name': 'Search Results',
       'item_list_id': 'SR123',
       'index': 1,
       'quantity': '1'
     },
     {
       'item_name': 'Donut Friday Scented T-Shirt',
       'item_id': '67890',
       'price': '33.75',
       'item_brand': 'Google',
       'item_category': 'Apparel',
       'item_category2': 'Mens',
       'item_category3': 'Shirts',
       'item_category4': 'Tshirts',
       'item_variant': 'Black',
       'item_list_name': 'Search Results',
       'item_list_id': 'SR123',
       'index': 2,
       'quantity': '1'
     }]
  }
});
```

Then in the GA4 debugger instead of showing 2 items it show up 4. 2 products and 2 list items as below:

1. Triblend Android T-Shirt (12345)
   item_id: 12345
   quantity: 1
   item_name: Triblend Android T-Shirt
   item_brand: Google
   item_category: Apparel
   item_category2: Mens
   item_category3: Shirts
   item_category4: Tshirts
   variant: Gray
   price: 15250000
2. Donut Friday Scented T-Shirt (67890)
   item_id: 67890
   quantity: 1
   item_name: Donut Friday Scented T-Shirt
   item_brand: Google
   item_category: Apparel
   item_category2: Mens
   item_category3: Shirts
   item_category4: Tshirts
   variant: Black
   price: 33750000
3. Item
   item_list_id: SR123
   item_list_name: Search Results
   index: 1
4. Item
   item_list_id: SR123
   item_list_name: Search Results
   index: 2

How do I manager to map the item_list_name and item_list_id to their corresponding products?

Comment: I'm getting the same exact thing. Another thing I noticed is that if you try to send more than 10 items in the array, the event will not appear in the GA4 debugger view.

Comment: I also noticed that. With large arrays debugger seems to have issues.

Comment: Yeap. I was going through the `google-tag-manager` tag on stackoverflow. I came across this answer which brought alot of insight. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66574826/splitting-up-large-requests-due-to-payload-size-issues

Comment: My current understanding is that, you are supposed to call `view_item_list` with `items` that the user is currently looking at in their screen. So you would be calling `view_item_list` multiple times. There is a 8kb payload size for the GTM request, hence large arrays would probably exceed that limit (can cross check in dev tools as well)

Comment: As for the "Item X" in the debugger, I think that should be normal. I came across another SO user with the same thing. A small sample size of the 3 of us looking at the same thing, I would think that is a normal behaviour for the GA4 Debugger. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66305584/google-analytics-4-ecommerce-problems-with-item-list-id-in-view-item-list